# output lmer summary information to word using ReporteRs

Tags: r, ms-word, lmer, reporters

I am using the package `ReporteRs` in `R` to output the results of statistical tests, and plots, to `Word 2010`.

I'm using `lmer` in the `lme4` package to do some analysis, and I would like to output the results of `summary(foo.lmer)` to Word. I wish to capture everything in the `lmerMod` object and put it into Word. For example, here's a `summary(foo.lmer)` result that I have:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: value ~ Drug * Time + (Time + 1 | ID)
Data: DWeight.Female

REML criterion at convergence: 2296.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3165 -0.6132  0.0343  0.6476  2.3088 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr
    ID   (Intercept) 573.98186 23.9579      
         Time          0.07738  0.2782  0.29
Residual              15.61168  3.9512      
Number of obs: 360, groups:  ID, 40

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)     270.44441    5.83694   46.33
Drug              1.24479    4.11450    0.30
Time              1.30481    0.07641   17.08
Drug:Time        -0.11055    0.05386   -2.05

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr)   Drug  Time  
Drug    -0.758              
Time     0.211 -0.160       
Drug:Tm -0.160  0.211 -0.758
```

How can I store this information, with the fixed widths and hard returns, so that I can output this information using ReporteRs? I could copy and paste, but I am trying to automate the output, and I am often re-writing over the output Word document.

The fixed effects output is the most essential part, however it would be very useful to have all the output copied into Word.

**update and resolution**
Thanks to the suggestion to use capture.output in the reply, this code worked for me, still using ReporteRs:

```
 D1male.Results <- capture.output(summary(D1Male.lmer))
 myBWdoc = docx()
 myBWdoc = addTitle( myBWdoc, "Drug 1 Results", level = 1 )
 myBWdoc = addTitle( myBWdoc, "Repeated Measures Models", level = 2 )
 myBWdoc = addParagraph( myBWdoc, D1male.Results)
```

If you want to put your response as an answer I can accept and upvote it.

Comment: Have you tried the capture.output() function? Something like outputmodel <- capture.output(yourmodel)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will add the information to my question in order to help anyone else that needs this addressed.

Comment: No thanks. Glad I could help. I am a uge fan of ReporteRs package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the capture.output() function. Like this:

```
Results <- capture.output(summary(your.lmer.model))
```

It stores the summary information in the new variable. After that you can use it in e.g. ReporteRs paragraph functions.

Comment: Pleased to accept your answer as correct and with an upvote. Thanks for your help!